# Converting pyspark dataframe into dictionary: result different than expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark, dictionary-comprehension

Let's imagine I have the following pyspark dataframe:

```
data = [("USA",20,40,60),
    ("India",50,40,30),
    ("Nepal",20,50,30),
    ("Ireland",40,60,70),
    ("Norway",50,50,60)
  ]

columns = ["country", "A", "B", "C"]
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)
```

To create a dictionary from it, I followed the following approach:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
list_test = [row.asDict() for row in df.collect()]
dict_test = {country['country']: country for country in list_test}
```

The result is as follows:

```
{'USA': {'country': 'USA', 'A': 20, 'B': 40, 'C': 60}, 'India': {'country': 'India', 'A': 50, 'B': 40, 'C': 30}, 'Nepal': {'country': 'Nepal', 'A': 20, 'B': 50, 'C': 30}, 'Ireland': {'country': 'Ireland', 'A': 40, 'B': 60, 'C': 70}, 'Norway': {'country': 'Norway', 'A': 50, 'B': 50, 'C': 60}}
```

However, what I wanted was the following:

```
{'USA': {'A': 20, 'B': 40, 'C': 60}, 'India': {'A': 50, 'B': 40, 'C': 30}, 'Nepal': {'A': 20, 'B': 50, 'C': 30}, 'Ireland': {'A': 40, 'B': 60, 'C': 70}, 'Norway': {'A': 50, 'B': 50, 'C': 60}}
```

How can I obtain this? I'm not sure I understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a dict comprehension to remove the unwanted item:

```
list_test = [row.asDict() for row in df.collect()]
dict_test = {country['country']: {k:v for k,v in country.items() if k != 'country'} for country in list_test}

print(dict_test)
{'USA': {'A': 20, 'B': 40, 'C': 60}, 'India': {'A': 50, 'B': 40, 'C': 30}, 'Nepal': {'A': 20, 'B': 50, 'C': 30}, 'Ireland': {'A': 40, 'B': 60, 'C': 70}, 'Norway': {'A': 50, 'B': 50, 'C': 60}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way by collecting the json string directly from the DataFrame after some transformations then using `json.loads` to get dict object:

```
import json
    
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_json, collect_list, struct, map_from_arrays

dict_test = json.loads(
    df.groupBy().agg(
        collect_list("country").alias("countries"),
        collect_list(struct("A", "B", "C")).alias("values")
    ).select(
        to_json(map_from_arrays("countries", "values")).alias("json_str")
    ).collect()[0].json_str
)

print(dict_test)

#{'USA': {'A': 20, 'B': 40, 'C': 60}, 'India': {'A': 50, 'B': 40, 'C': 30}, 'Nepal': {'A': 20, 'B': 50, 'C': 30}, 'Ireland': {'A': 40, 'B': 60, 'C': 70}, 'Norway': {'A': 50, 'B': 50, 'C': 60}}
```